# display specific div or content based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to display a div containing some content to be URL specific. 
So only show div on pages that contain specified URL, for example:

if URL is equal to any one of the following:

```
/makeup/face/foundation/compact-loose-powder/luminous-silk-compact-case/3614270283604.html
/makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/designer-lift-foundation/3605521491268.html
/makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/power-fabric-foundation/ww-00049-arm.html
/makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/maestro-fusion-makeup/AP10123.html
/makeup/face/foundation/face-fabric/ww-00115-arm.html
```

Show the following div:

```
<div class="container-content">content</div>
```

else hide it.

I ave tried the following with no success:

```
 var paths = ['/makeup/face/foundation/compact-loose-powder/luminous-silk- 
 compact-case/3614270283604.html', '/makeup/face/foundation/compact-loose- 
 powder/luminous-silk-compact-case/3614270283604.html', '/makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/power-fabric-foundation/ww-00049-arm.html', '/makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/maestro-fusion-makeup/AP10123.html', '/makeup/face/foundation/face-fabric/ww-00115-arm.html'];
 $('.container-content').toggle(paths.indexOf(location.path) != -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Place the local paths in to an array, then test to see if the current location matches any of those paths:

```
var paths = ['/en-us/mens/designers/brunello_cucinelli', '/en-us/mens/grooming', '/en-us/mens/shoes'];
$('.container-content').toggle(paths.indexOf(location.path) != -1);
```

Comment: Thanks - doing the check and fallback option is the part i'm having most difficulty with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. These two lines of code cover the goal of your question. Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: how about using some? ```paths.some(c => c == location.path)```

Comment: @Jorge yep, that'd work too so long as you don't need to support < IE9

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan I can see its working because display:none is applied to the div but doesn't seem to be picking up the URLs as its not displaying at all. No error in console either?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `doesn't seem to be picking up the URLs as its not displaying at all` as if `display: none` is on the element then it won't be displayed - that's the point

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan apologies for the misunderstanding. the div needs to be visible on the list of URLs provided but hidden on the rest. does that make sense?

Comment: In that case change `!=` to `==` and set them to hidden by default in CSS

Answer (score 0):

This no longer necessitate use of jQuery as the Liquid object request retrieve current path: 
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/request

So this should do the trick :

```
{%- capture urls -%}
/makeup/face/foundation/compact-loose-powder/luminous-silk-compact-case/3614270283604.html, /makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/designer-lift-foundation/3605521491268.html, /makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/power-fabric-foundation/ww-00049-arm.html, /makeup/face/foundation/liquid-foundation/maestro-fusion-makeup/AP10123.html, /makeup/face/foundation/face-fabric/ww-00115-arm.html
{%- endcapture - %}

{% if urls contains request.path %}
<div class="container-content">content</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi @alicegirard I am not using shopify nor liquid templates. I need a JS solution to get current URL

Comment: My bad, got this in Liquid alerts, do not know why ;).